# How to change subtitle of each list_Tile separately

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I have a List_view in my first screen which its title is filled with a list of string, by tapping on each item of list_view a new page is showing up which calculate a value and send back this value to the first screen and I need this calculated value to be shown only on subtitle of the selected item of list view, not all the subtitles as happened in my code!
what should I do?

This is my first screen's `List_view`:

```
ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: MyList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, position){
                    return Card(
                            child:ListTile(
                              title:Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  MyList.isEmpty ? "click button to add movement": selectedMovementList.elementAt(position), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),),
                              ),
                             //Here is my problem!!!!!!!
                            subtitle: Text(subTileInfoText),
                            trailing:Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                            onTap:() {
                              _awaitReturnValueFromDetailScreen(context,position);
                                },
                            ),
                          );
                        }
 void _awaitReturnValueFromDetailScreen(BuildContext context,int position) async {

// start the SecondScreen and wait for it to finish with a result
final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => detailMovementEntry(selectedMovementList.elementAt(position)),
    ));

// after the SecondScreen result comes back update the Text widget with it
setState(() {
  subTileInfoText = result;
});
```

}

And this is my second screen's send back data:

```
RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('Save'),
          onPressed: (){
            _sendDataBack(context);

          },)
void _sendDataBack(BuildContext context) {
     String textToSendBack = "SomeText"
      Navigator.pop(context, textToSendBack);
```

}

I need only the subtitle of the selected tile being changed not all of the tile's subtitle!

Comment: you can return an object, (index + subtitle), then you will know what index you will have to change the subtitle :)

Comment: The problem is there is no place to insert the index for subtitle (I have mentioned the place for adding subtitle in my code My question is how to change the subtitle text by knowing the index of selected tile! @diegoveloper

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!!
The problem is solved by defining a list of subtitles(named: `subList`) and in `_awaitReturnValueFromDetailScreen` I put the returned value in `subList[position]`, and in `subtitle` I just read from this list.